# how to update a table in spring data JPA using where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to update particular record in a table and i am using primary key(empId) and one more column(empSalary) to identify the particular column. As we know primary key(empId) is enough to identify the record. But in my case i want update the record if that employee salary is 1000. is there any option to update a record using entity not query?. I am using spring data JPA

Example:

```
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column
    private int empId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private float salary;

    @Column
    private String state;

    // getters, setters
}
```

I want to update the whole table if empId and salary match with table.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please let me know, I can help more if it was not. You haven't accepted it as the answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an `EmployeeRepository` create the following method;

`findOneByEmpIdAndSalary(Integer empId, Float salary);`

Then you can pass the `salary = 1000.0` or can create a default method within the same repository with that value hard coded;

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    Optional<Employee> findOneByEmpIdAndSalary(Integer empId, Float salary);

    default Optional<Employee> findOneByEmpIdAndSalaryEqualTo1000(Integer empId) {
        return findOneByEmpIdAndSalary(empId, 1000.0);
    }
}
```

I used `findOne` since you are already selecting with the primary key plus an extra condition, so you will either get one or none, thus using `Optional<T>` as the result, to control either possibility in a better way.

After fetching this entity within a `@Transactional` state, just update the resulting entity. If `Optional` is not empty, then the ending of the transaction will commit that update to the DB, else nothing.

```
@Transactional
public String updateWithCondition(Integer empId) {
    employeeRepository.findOneByEmpIdAndSalaryEqualTo1000(empId)
            .ifPresent(employee -> employee.setState("desired Update"));
}
```

Like the above snippet as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Modifying` along with `@Query` annotation to include where clause in your query. This way you save a round trip to DB by fetching the entity first and then updating it.

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation) article from Baeldung explains it neatly. Hope it helps.